# xmlrpcresp Object read print the values in php

Tags: php

Can anyone please guide me read values from xmlrpcresp Object

```
xmlrpcresp Object ( [val] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 11) [1] => Array ( [Id] => 55 ) [2] => Array ( [Id] => 88 ) ) [valtyp] => phpvals [errno] => 0 [errstr] => [payload] => [hdrs] => Array ( [server] => Apache-Coyote/1.1 [pragma] => no-cache [cache-control] => no-cache, no-store [expires] => Fri, 01 Aug 2014 02:36:52 GMT [content-type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8 [content-length] => 422 [date] => Thu, 31 Jul 2014 14:36:52 GMT [set-cookie] => app-lb=3858956298.20480.0000; path=/ ) [_cookies] => Array ( [app-lb] => Array ( [value] => 3858956298.20480.0000 [path] => / ) ) [content_type] => text/xml )
```

I am trying to fetch the array value val

```
( [val] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 11) [1] => Array ( [Id] => 55 ) [2] => Array ( [Id] => 88 ) )
```

How to get this val and want print last value too I am new to php.

Thanks in advance

Jagdish

Comment: `$datArray = $object_var->val`?

Comment: Thank you Sterling Archer its my bad wrong syntax I was tried.